# How to display something in a div when the user clicks on a text in another div - no page refresh

Tags: php, customization, jquery, ajax, javascript

I am trying to make some customizations to my site, but I got stuck at this point.

I have two divs and I put into the first div the names of some product tags.

Now I need that when I click on one of these names - to display a shortcode in the second div.

And for generating the shortcode I need to use the ID of the product tag as one of the arguments so I think I need to also somehow temporary store the ID.

This has to be done without refreshing the page so I'm guessing I would need to use AJAX. But here is the problem: I don't have AJAX knowledge so I'm not sure what to do here.

This is my code up until now:

```
<div class="modal-content">

<div class="modal-body">      
  <h3>Section I:</h3>      
<?php 
  //Here I obtain an array with the product tags of a product with an ID of 62:
  $term_list = wp_get_post_terms(62, 'product_tag', array("fields" => "all"));
  //I list the product tags obtained:
  if ( $term_list ){
  foreach ($term_list as $term){
  echo $term->name; 
  }
  }
?>  
</div>
<hr/>

<div class="modal-body">
  <h3>Section II:</h3>
  <p>Here should be displayed the shortcode, based on the product tag the user chose to click in the Section I.</p>    
</div>

</div>
```

*Some more details:*

I actually am building a WooCommerce site (that's why I have products and product tags). The shortcode is going to display a calendar.

For creating the calendars I am using a plugin called "Pinpoint Booking System PRO" and this plugin gives me the option to set the ID of the calendar myself so I set it to the same value as the ID of the product tag. Because I'm trying to associate a calendar to each product tag.

So that - when a user clicks on a tag name that I display in the section 1 - I'd be able to use the  ID of that product tag as a parameter in the shortcode, that looks like this: [dopbsp id=5] and display the associated calendar.

I hope someone can help! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you please add more technical information? what values will be passed to the shortcode? and what is the content of that shortcode?

Comment: While this does not address your specific need, this guide will give you a good general understanding of how to use ajax within WP.   Carve out a few hours to learn the concepts here (well presented) and you can apply to your own solution.  Repost with any specific questions:
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/

Comment: @Jack Johansson: Thank you for your answer and interest in my question! I was trying to keep it as simple as possible and not complicate the question with too much details, but sure I can provide more background information and details. I edited my initial question and added more info after the code.

Comment: @jdm2112 : Thank you for your answer! I'll try checking it out. I'm interested in learning, just that when I tried AJAX I felt a bit overwelmed and didn't know where to start. So it's for sure a useful resource!